# Is there a more space efficient way of storing images in a DB other than as a blob?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image

In what formats can image be saved in database else than blob ? I know we can save it as blob type .The easiest way . But is there any other way possible . becuase using php in every case we convert the image into a string . than save it  .

SO someone with a different answer ?

Comment: Don't store them in the DB at all. Store their location and let the filesystem store and serve them.

Comment: upload the image to the server and save the path to it in the database

Comment: Recommend you don't store images in the database: store the image file in the server filesystem, and a reference to that file in the database

Comment: Why isn't recommended??..in what cases it's good to store in a DB?

Comment: yes that a way i know . But in some hard and fast case . if storing the image is the only option . Than any other way than blob type

Comment: There isn't a good situation to store images in a database. Try answering this question; what problem are you solving, saving blobs or binary safe strings in the database for image handling?

Comment: If you're absolutely against storing files on the file system, I've found Mongo's GridFS great for file storage in databases. Much easier to work with than MySQL, for one, since it does the chunking etc by itself. You could store the files in Mongo and store the ObjectID in your database.

Comment: yes , some image processing script to find the the percentage of each color used in the image .

Comment: @xbonez : ok thats great .  I want something like that only .

Comment: What have got _against_ storing images as blob type? You say " I know we can save it as blob type .The easiest way" does that mean you are looking for a more complex way to store them!? If you want to put images in the DB grab example code from the web and move on, I just don't see any point in you asking this question.

Comment: i am looking for a way which is more efficient and less space consuming

Comment: So your question should have been titled "is there a more space efficient way of storing images in a DB other than as a blob?"

Comment: @Tony : I think i tried to ask the same question . any other way than blog  .

Comment: @Tony - Remember, not everyone's native language is english ;) I will edit the question to suit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could covert them to Base64 and store them as strings. However, the practice of storing images in DB is not something that is usually done for several reasons:

1. It's easier to store pictures on a server and then have paths stored in DB
2. Can't really index these pictures well
3. DB's grow too fast, can't replicate or backup efficiently

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if if dont use BASE64 encoding .

Comment: it was just the first thing that came to my mind. Not strictly neccessary.